# Как в питоне создать класс через Input

Tags: python, ооп

Как через input создать класс т.е.
а = input()
Как создать класс чтобы название класса было то что ввели в "а"

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Зачем это делать?

Comment: а = input()
class """то что ввели в a"""

Answer (score 2):

Совершенно неясно зачем Вам нужно это, но давайте попробуем сделать так:

```py
# Принимаем пользовательский ввод и сохраняем его...
class_name = input()

# Создаем экземпляр, в качестве названия ему укажем пользовательский ввод...
my_class = type(class_name, (object,), {})

# Проверяем: видим что название соответствует пользовательскому вводу...
print(my_class.__name__)
```